# Materializecss datepicker Date display issue

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, materialize

I am using Materializecss' datepicker function as part of a form.  When the user clicks the input and inputs a chosen date, the input is correctly formatted as shown:

[image]

I created this format with Angular by doing:

```
<div class="input-field col l4">
   <input value="" ng-model="note.contactHistoryNoteDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'" id="contactHistoryNoteDate1{{$index}}" type="text" class="datepicker addnote">
   <label for="contactHistoryNoteDate1">DATE</label>
</div>
```

However, when I allow the user to edit the form, and I pull the date from the model, it looks like this (despite formatting):
[image]

Anyone know how to fix the formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set setDefaultDate to true;

```
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 1, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    format: "mm dd yyyy",
    setDefaultDate: true
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your date format when you initialize datepicker -

CODE:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
    format: 'mm dd yyyy' });
```

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately

Comment: Okay let me try for another way.

Answer (score 0):

Try these format. It may works for you

`format: 'd mmmm, yyyy',`

`format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',`

`$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  format: 'd mmmm, yyyy', // Default format
   selectMonths: true,
     selectYears: 15
   });`

`$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', // Default format
   selectMonths: true,
     selectYears: 15
   });`